# Understanding Makefile += operator

Tags: makefile

I have a line in my kernel make file:

```
obj-y   += sample.o adc.o trigger.o send.o
```

I don't understand the above line. Is it same as the following?

```
obj-y  +=sample.o
obj-y  +=adc.o
obj-y  +=trigger.o
obj-y  +=send.o
```

Comment: try `echo` each after `+=`.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [GNU `make` manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Appending), `+=` is used to append strings to variables. So yes.